# How to display exec output into a text area

Tags: javascript, php, linux, exec

I have a page where on button click, calls a javascript function that executes the following:

```
 <?php $i = exec('/etc/init.d/iptables status'); ?>

  document.getElementById('txtArea').innerHTML += <?php echo $i; ?>;
```

but the text area stood empty, 
any advice or solution?

Comment: Paste your HTML markup and JS code you wrote by now.

Comment: what kind of element is txtArea? a div? an input? something else?

Comment: And why do you concatenate your `txtArea`?

Comment: I want to add the rules of iptables into the text area, the idea is to display the values into a display item in HTML, text area or input text it doesnt matter

Comment: Duvdevan how can i put the output of exec into the text area?

Comment: @user3132623 The `exec` returns only the last row. Probably you want to add the second parameter (an array) to collect all output.

Comment: @GáborBakos it returns this value: function Array() { [native code] }

Answer (score 1):

PHP output into HTML:

```
<textarea><?php echo shell_exec('/etc/init.d/iptables status'); ?></textarea>
```

PHP output into HTML, but in form of a Javascript Value Update on the Textarea element:

```
<textarea id="txtArea">...</a>
<script>
document.getElementById("txtArea").value = "<?php echo shell_exec('/etc/init.d/iptables status'); ?>";
</script>
```

But i doubt, that you want this.

So, finally the whole thingy again, but now with a button as the trigger for a JS/jQuery Ajax Get request:

```
<textarea id="txtArea">...</a>

<input type="button" id="txtAreaUpdateButton" value="Update Textarea"/>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#txtAreaUpdateButton').click(function() {
      $.ajax({ 
          type: "GET",
          url: "http://www.yoursite.com/request.php",//get response from this file
          success: function(response){ 
            $("textarea#txtArea").val(response); // update textarea with response
        }
      });
   });
});
</script>
```

Here 'request.php' contains:

```
<?php echo shell_exec('/etc/init.d/iptables status'); ?>
```

Keep an eye on the quotes. They are often the source for errors.

Comment: Thanks @Jens-André Koch for the solution, i have the problem in shell_exec, if i edit the request.php to use exec command it returns the last line but with shell_exec the page is blank even if I add something else. I checked the sudeors and safe_mode is off in php.ini..is shell_exec has another security requirements?

Comment: Hmm, maybe a permissions thing. Take a look at the folder and file permissions. Is the PHP user able to exec the command? Ìf you don't know the user run: `shell_exec('whoami');` and then use chown to change perms. -- Please try to enable error reporting: `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('track_errors',1); ini_set('display_errors',1);` and then take a look a the log files to trace the shell_exec() problem down. You might also test with a simple ls exec, like `shell_exec('ls -la /home');`, just to see if you get the execution working.

Comment: Jens i used chown for the user apache on the directory iptables. I activated as well the error reporting, but no logs were added. The ls is executed. For the iptable is there something i missed other than chown -R?

Comment: Strange. What about `echo shell_exec('iptables --list');`?

Comment: Give this a try `chmod +x /etc/init.d/iptables`

Comment: still same issue..no chmod either chown, I restarted the VM maybe there is some services that need restart..no change. I am guessing this statement: to let php user start or do something on a service, he must use the sbin folder where only the root can access it..so..any clue??